# Partial String Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, trie

I am trying to find out if there is an algorithm that exists that is capable of the following:

Given a list of strings:

```
{"56B99Z", "78K80F", "50B49J", "28F11F"}
```

And given an input string of:

```
"??B?9?"
```

Then the algorithm should output:

```
{"56B99Z", "50B49J"}
```

Where ? are uknown characters.

I think some sort of trie-tree with additional links between nodes could work, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if this has been done before.

Comment: Please specify a bit more about your question.

Comment: From your sample example, it seems the length of the strings are same. Please specify whether this is a constraint of this problem. Searching for strings of same length vs variable length may change the way of solving this problem.

Comment: The length of the string isn't a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague and you  need to be more specific, are the strings have the same size? If so you can just look on the position which aren't question mark in your string you search for each other string, anyway if you looking for matching strings algorithms I suggest you read about kmp algorithm which have linear complexity for the given input => https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: An algorithm that works for strings of varying lengths would be better than one that only works for a specified length. Both would be valid answers to the question.  Im idealy looking for something that would be performant with millions of strings, so a brute force aproach of looking at positions one by one is not ideal. I shall take a look at KMP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to match on the 1,2,4,6 positions as an \w